# Fixed-size table in iOS WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

What i want to achieve is to have a "Header label" that is always visible on the top, a table in the middle which can have multiple items and its scrollable, and two buttons "Left" and "Right" which are always visible on the bottom. 
Example:

[image]

To achieve this i add the table in a fix sized group, but this way the table is not scrollable.

If i add the table without a group, then the whole screen becomes scrollable which doesn't solve my problem. 
Example:

[image]

Is this even possible with the current API?

Comment: :Have you got any solution for that,if yes please help us  for same :)

Comment: @Jovan did you got solution for this?

Comment: Sorry guys, no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

If you want scrollable table inside group use `size to fit content` in group settings but probably it won't behave as you want.

**Details**

First of all currently (2nd February 2015) it's not possible to have some elements static and some of them dynamic in one InterfaceController. If you have scrollable content (like table) all elements on this InterfaceController will be scrollable.

So, you can use solution from TL;DR section but as I said it probably won't behave as you want.
I had similar problem: to set image as static background table but didn't manage to solve it, even if you set image as table background it won't be static.

**Note**

From Apple's Human Interface Guidelines

> Do not embed tables inside groups. Tables resize dynamically based on the number of rows they contain. As a result, tables ignore any height restrictions placed on them by groups.
>   (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/Tables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014992-CH24-SW1)

Comment: Thanks, but you guessed it right - it doesn't work :) Size to fit content works the same as the second screenshot I posted. I don't know why Apple doesn't allow this functionality yet.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want to achieve is the following:
https://www.apple.com/watch/films/#film-design
Look at (6:47 - 6:50).

Although this feature is shown in the apple commercial, its not yet supported in the current WatchKit SDK.